# regex to match if string has dot as its first occurenc?

Tags: regex, typescript

I have to write regex to match regex to match if  string has dot as its first occurence.

I want 5
to match below string

> .hello

The string which starts with dot

Below strings not have to match:

> helo.h

I have tried like below but it wont work

```
/\.(.*)/g
```

https://regexr.com/4ibiu

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^\..*`

Comment: also add multiline flag to see it on regexr

Comment: @Thefourthbird, no i just want to match string which has dot as 1st character

Comment: This info can be found in any regex cheatsheet. Click on your link (regexr), click "RegEx reference" in the left menu, click "Anchors", click "beginning" and then use eyes (eyes is on the face) to read the description.

Comment: That pattern will match a string which starts with a dot (It will also match a single dot) https://regex101.com/r/CI2mAE/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, only single dot

Comment: @Thefourthbird, you given regex wont match anything https://regexr.com/4ibjg

Comment: @kumaresan_sd You have to enable the multiline flag at the right top.

Comment: So there should be a single dot at the start, can it be followed by another dot? can there be more dots in the string?

Comment: @kumaresan_sd There are answers provided which solve your issue. You might accept one of those and perhaps upvote the ones that have been proven helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for my question is

https://regexr.com/4ibl0

Answer is given by @The fourth bird

Answer (score 2):

you can try the following :

`^\..+$`

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
.+ matches any character (except for line terminators)
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

https://regex101.com/r/1WQHWA/1

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

`/(^\..+)/`

[regexr.com/4ibjd](http://regexr.com/4ibjd)

Just note that this will also match a string of all dots. If you want a word after a single dot, you can try something like this: `/(^\.[a-z]+)/`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[^a-z](\.(.*))
```

it basicly does the same as you have, and defines that there shouldn't be a a-z in front of the match